# Protected shell in embedded linux

Tags: linux, embedded

When I run `telnetd -l /bin/sh` on an embedded Linux device and use Putty to telnet to it, the provided shell is `/bin/psh` (protected shell).

On this device, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/busybox`.

Where I can see on this system that `/bin/sh` redirects to `/bin/psh`?

How can I change it if `/bin` is read only?

Comment: Maybe the user's shell is set to `/bin/psh` in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: @multithr3at3d no. There is `/bin/sh`

Comment: @Meryy that's not the point. The point was whether the user is configured to use /bin/psh when logging in. That is, /etc/passwd has the shell set that way (see `chsh` on full-blown systems). Typically your alternative shells will also have to be in `/etc/shells` so as to be eligible as login shells.

Answer (score 1):

First you can ask where the shell lies with `which sh`. The command tells the full path.

Then, you can use `ls - al` to view whether or not that is a symbolic link on its own or not.

Once you have found the original shell you know whether or not it fits your need.

To change the shell for the user you are using, you have plenty of choices, depending on whether or not you are root. Have a look [here](https://www.tecmint.com/change-a-users-default-shell-in-linux/) to have an idea.

If, instead, you want to change where the symbolic link points, you can you have to be root and use the `ln` command. Keep in mind that changing the shell in this way can have serious unwanted consequences.